# Issue with ajax call on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple div with class `"btn-custom btn-custom-primary"`. The AJAX call is not loading on `.btn-custom` click event but when I check on network section in console tab the data is returned through ajax success: function (data) but when i debug the code it throws  "data is not defined" reference error and there is no error in console. Please help.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn-custom', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var bid = $(this).attr('bid');
  $('.btn-custom').removeClass('btn-custom-selected').addClass("btn-custom-primary");
  $(this).removeClass("btn-custom-primary").addClass('btn-custom-selected');
  var HostelId = getParameterByName("id", window.location.href);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?secController=School&action=fetchActiveStatusOfRoom',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    async: false,
    data: {
      id: HostelId,
      RoomId: id
    },
    success: function(data) {

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: remove `dataType: 'JSON',` and also add a `error ( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )` function to your ajax so that you can output the error to the console.

Comment: Where is it throwing data is not defined? Inside the success method?

Comment: I added    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }

Comment: no error is alerting

Comment: @epascarello: when i debug the code in browsers console

Comment: Try changing data to `data: {"id": HostelId, "RoomId": id},`

Comment: debug where in the console? If you do not have a break point set inside the success method, of course data is undefined since the variable is only available inside the function...

Comment: Also `dataType` is not the format on which you are sending data. It is actually the format of which you expect data to be received.

Comment: the format of data is like0: {_id: {$oid: "5bd2f7cdd2ccda0c60007654"}, Name: "Modern School Dormitiory", RoomStatusDetails: [,…],…}

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error.